# Get token for firebase admin authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

this is my function, for firebase function:

```js
export const hello = onRequest({ cors }, async (request, response) => {
  const token = request.headers.authorization?.split('Bearer ')[1]

  if (token) {
    const tokenData = await getAuth().verifyIdToken(token, true)
    response.send({
      status: 'success',
      data: tokenData.email
    })
  } else {
    response.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
  }
})
```

I don't like how I'm getting token here, but that's the only way I found:

`request.headers.authorization?.split('Bearer ')[1]`

is there any better way? Let's say, maybe admin itself has some built in method?

Answer (score 0):

The `verifyIdToken()` requires only the JWT token as first parameter. The `'Bearer '` just indicates that the request uses Bearer token system. If you just add the token in your API request you won't have to parse the string to get the token part.  
The Admin SDK does not have any built-in function for that.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`onCall()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) instead of `onRequest()` that'll handle the authentication part and you can read user's information from `context.auth` object.

Comment: I'm not sending token. Firebase is sending it automatically.  I'm just `await signInWithPopup(auth, githubProvider)`

Am I doing anything wrong? is there any way to skipt Bearer? 

in case of onCall not able to get Request. but will try one more time.

Comment: @Lasharela how are you calling the Cloud Function exactly? Can you please edit your question and add the frontend code? Also what is the `getToken()` function?

Comment: `getToken` is basically `request.headers.authorization?.split('Bearer ')[1]`

Comment: @Lasharela and where is the authorization token being added from? You must be calling the cloud function somewhere and that is why I asked for your frontend code.